# How to show addicional information popup in auto-complete using IContentAssistProcessor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, editor

I created a custom eclipse editor (`AbstractDecoratedTextEditor`) and I implemented an auto-complete feature using `IContentAssistProcessor`.

In the class thats extends `IContentAssistProcessor`, I overrided the method `computeCompletionProposals` that returns a list of `ICompletionProposal`.

But when the auto-complete dialog is running, I cant show the additional information in yellow dialog like in Java.

For example, in Java I have the Javadoc dialog:

[image]

But in my custom auto-complete I cant create this yellow dialog to show additional information.

How can I create this dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the *additional information popup* to show, you need two things:

1. `ICompletionProposal#getAdditionalProposalInfo()` must return a string that contains the information, that's what you probably already have.
2. the `ContentAssistant` that is used to show the proposals must have an `IInformationControlCreator` set. Use `contentAssistant.setInformationControlCreator()` to assign one. Here is an example of an information control creator:

```java
class SimpleInformationControlCreator implements IInformationControlCreator {
  public IInformationControl createInformationControl( Shell shell ) {
    return new DefaultInformationControl( shell, true );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works... I tried use only getAdditionalProposalInfo. Do you know how to show the first dialog and the yellow dialog bigger?